# How to hide the real URL when cursor is pointed and show only pretty URL?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url

I have a gallery where the pretty URL works on the browser bar ([www.rajeevthomas.com/photos/Distant-Lands/Intensity-Of-Red/](http://rajeevthomas.com/photos/Distant-Lands/Intensity-Of-Red/)). But the images and buttons ( next and previous image buttons ) show the real URLs (xyz.com/viewgallery.php?cname=Distant-Lands&pcaption=Layers-Of-Light-II) when the cursor is pointed at them ( on the bottom of the page ) . How can I just show pretty URLs when cursor is pointed at images?

You can see this here http://rajeevthomas.com/photos/Distant-Lands/Intensity-Of-Red/

The large image code is

```
// display previous and next links if more than one photo 

else if( $pcaption ) 
{   

mysql_query("UPDATE gallery_photos SET photo_caption = REPLACE(photo_caption,'\\\','') ");

$pcaption = str_replace("-", " ",$pcaption);
$pcaption = str_replace("%27", "'",$pcaption);
$pcaption = str_replace("\\", "",$pcaption);


$result = mysql_query( "SELECT photo_caption, photo_description, photo_filename,photo_keywords FROM gallery_photos WHERE photo_caption='".addslashes($pcaption)."'" ); 

list($photo_caption, $photo_description, $photo_filename, $photo_keywords) = mysql_fetch_array( $result ); 

$nr = mysql_num_rows( $result ); 
mysql_free_result( $result );     

$p_caption = $photo_caption;
$p_description = $photo_description;
$p_keywords = $photo_keywords;

//fill caption_array with sorted pids in current category 

$caption_array = array();
$result = mysql_query( "SELECT photo_caption FROM gallery_photos WHERE category_name='".addslashes($cname)."' " ); 
$ct = mysql_num_rows( $result ); 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 

$row[0]= trim($row[0]);
$row[0] = str_replace(" ","-",$row[0]);
$row[0] = str_replace("'","%27",$row[0]);
$caption_array[] = trim($row[0]); 
} 

mysql_free_result( $result ); 

if( empty($nr ) ) 
{ 
$result_final = "\t<tr><td>***No Photo found*******</td></tr>\n"; 
} 
else 
{ 
$category_name = $cname; 
$cname = str_replace(" ", "-", $cname); 
$result_final = "
<div class=limagePage>
<div class=llink><a href=/viewgallery.php>ALBUMS</a><span class=arrow>&gt;&gt</span><a href=/viewgallery.php?cname=$cname>$category_name</a></div>
";

// display previous and next links if more than one photo 
$next=0;
$prev=0;

if ($ct > 1) 
{ 
$pcaption = trim($pcaption);
$pcaption = str_replace(" ","-",$pcaption);
$pcaption = str_replace("'","%27",$pcaption);
$key = array_search($pcaption , $caption_array); 
$prev = $key - 1; 
if ($prev < 0) $prev = $ct - 1; 
$next = $key + 1; 
if ($next == $ct) $next = 0; 
$total_count= count($caption_array);
$result_final .= "<div class='prevnext'>"; 
$result_final .= "<span class='prev'><a href=/viewgallery.php?cname=$cname&pcaption=".$caption_array[$next]."><img src=/photos/assets/left.png  border=0 ></a></span>"; 
$result_final .= "<span class='next'><a href=/viewgallery.php?cname=$cname&pcaption=".$caption_array[$prev].">
<img src=/photos/assets/right.png  border=0 ></a></span>"; 
$result_final .= "</div>";  

}            
}
$cname = str_replace(" ", "-", $cname);
$images_dir =str_replace(".","",$images_dir);
#$result_final .= "<div class=limage><table><tr><td><table class=image><tr>\n\t<td><a href=/viewgallery.php?cname=$cname&pcaption=".$caption_array[$next].">
#<img   src='".$images_dir."/".$photo_filename."' border='0' alt='".$photo_keywords."' /></a>
#<div class=caption>".$photo_caption."</div> 
#<div class='excerpt'>".$photo_description."</div> 
#</td>                    
#</tr></table></td></tr></table><div class=underline></div></div>
#<!-- .limagePage --></div> ";  

$result_final .= "<div class=limage><table><tr><td><table class=image><tr>\n\t<td><a href=/viewgallery.php?cname=$cname&pcaption=".$caption_array[$next].">
<img src='".$images_dir."/".$photo_filename."' border='0' alt='".$photo_keywords."'/></a>
<div class=caption>".$photo_caption."</div> 
<div class='excerpt'>".$photo_description."</div> 
</td>                    
</tr></table></td></tr></table><div class=underline></div></div>
<!-- .limagePage --></div>  ";
```

Answer (score 3):

Link to the pretty URL in the first place.

Comment: Quentin,I am sorry I don't understand your answer. I am a newbie at this. I am sorry if I am not clear. But if you go to this page http://rajeevthomas.com/photos/Distant-Lands/Intensity-Of-Red/ you will see that the browser bar shows pretty URLs but when we point the cursor on the large image or the next or previous image button the ugly URLs shows up like this www.rajeevthomas.com/viewgallery.php?cname=Distant-Lands&pcaption=Intensity-Of-Red I am wondering how I can hide the ugly URLs and show just the pretty ones.

Comment: Change `<a href='/viewgallery.php?cname=Distant-Lands&pcaption=Intensity-Of-R‌​ed'>` to `<a href='/photos/Distant-Lands/Intensity-Of-Red'>`

Comment: That's what I want to do. I was able to do it for the browser bar but the ugly URL shows up when the cursor is pointed at the image ( on the bottom of the page ). Not sure how it is done. Is this done in PHP?

Comment: That seems likely. You haven't shown us the relevant code though.

Comment: This is some hideous code. I think Quentin's already answered your question - change where you're building your link to. Also, your inconsistent use of quotes in your html attributes makes this really hard to read. Don't rely on add_slashes() for securing your SQL queries either - use prepared statements instead ( http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php )

Comment: Quentin and Josh, since my link is dynamically generated how can I change it to pretty URLs? ( when my cursor points towards images? not on the browser bar ) I am trying to improve my PHP , I know I am nowhere near :) Besides my quotes usage and using add slashes , is there anything else I need to so to improve my code?